# Android project crashes whenever a Maps fragment is in the layouts xml

Tags: android, eclipse, crash, google-maps-api-2

I'm currently trying to build an app with Google Map APIv2 for Android. I have spent a few hours trying to debug this error and have found nothing. I even tried creating

All I ever get when I try to include maps API fragment is "Unfortunately, myapp has"

**LogCat**

```
10-21 02:13:05.563: D/dalvikvm(2183): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 61K, 4% free 3523K/3660K, paused 0ms, total 15ms

    10-21 02:13:05.643: D/(2183): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8207700, tid 2183
    10-21 02:13:05.663: W/EGL_emulation(2183): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
    10-21 02:13:05.663: D/OpenGLRenderer(2183): Enabling debug mode 0
    10-21 02:13:05.683: D/dalvikvm(2183): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 99K, 5% free 3886K/4064K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
    10-21 02:13:12.003: D/AndroidRuntime(2183): Shutting down VM
    10-21 02:13:12.003: W/dalvikvm(2183): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0cb0b20)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183): Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 2183
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     ... 11 more
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:714)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.onClick_Login(MainActivity.java:51)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     ... 14 more
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:597)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4778)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     ... 21 more
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.myapp.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.myapp-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:583)
10-21 02:13:12.013: E/AndroidRuntime(2183):     ... 24 more
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="HIDDEN" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**activity**

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonLogout" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonLogout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="onClick_Logout"
        android:text="Logout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show your activity code...

Comment: did you import the `google-play-services_lib`?